# __NSArrayI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString: in parse data

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I making an app that fetches data from a Parse backend, saves it in to string & sets this string an a UILabel.

I've encountered the following error:

```
 `__NSArrayI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`
```

Here is my code

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MapInfo"];
[query whereKey:@"GPIN" equalTo:self.qpinString];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)   
{
    if (!error)
    {
        self.addedBy=[objects valueForKey:@"AddedBy"];
        self.address=[objects valueForKey:@"Address"];
        NSString *addedby=self.addedBy;
        NSLog(@"%@",[[[addedby stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]);
     }
}
```

I've tried using the following code

```
self.nameLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.addedBy];
```

And I don't see an error, but I get label text with backers, white space and parenthesis. I'm trying to trim the string I encounter the above error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check the data type of value '[objects valueForKey:@"AddedBy"]'. Maybe it is an array, not a string !

Comment: @HoàngToản yes it was array but i not get string please give me solution.

Comment: Why did you not include the actual error message????

Comment: The "solution" is to use the data types you are given rather than just guessing.  Start by figuring out what the complete structure of `objects` is.

Comment: replace your code: 'NSString *addedby=self.addedBy;' by: NSString *addedby = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.addedBy];. Now addedBy is a string, and maybe your log will not be error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling a method that should be applied to a NSString but you're using a NSArray instead.  Check the data types that are being returned by `valueForKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the class by using

```
NSLog(@"class - %@",[[objects valueForKey:@"AddedBy"]class]);
```

If it shows NSArray then you are applying

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString
```

to NSArray and not on NSString.

Comment: it shows me __NSArrayI class now how i replace it please give me solution.

Comment: Enumerate the array using a for loop or enumeration. And get the required data. Paste the data over here. And I can help you better.

Comment: but here i get only one value for each valueForKey

Comment: If you are sure there will be only one value then you can take the value out of the array using     [objects valueForKey:@"AddedBy"][0] in a string. Then use it on a label

Comment: Please share the data that you are getting. It will be more clear then.

Comment: The objects variable is an NSArray. Enumerate objects and check what is the data type using what i told u in my answer. You need to understand how NSArray is used and how to fetch values from it.